# Return function result with "throw" is this correct way to use throw?

Tags: javascript, throw

One of my colleagues send me this code block:

```js
export const getFieldChoice = (key, listName, fieldName) => {
  const value = cache.get(key) || { status: "new", data: null }

  if (value.status === "resolved") {
    return value.data
  }
  const data = spApi.lists.getByTitle(listName).fields.getByInternalNameOrTitle(fieldName).select('Choices').get().then(x => {
    value.data = x
    value.status = "resolved"
    cache.set(key, value)
  })
  throw data
}
```

Then I saw that he returns the promise data with `throw`. Is this the correct way to use `throw`?

Comment: "Is this correct way to use throw?" No. It's not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There're a couple of issues with the code and your understanding of the code...

1. `data` **is not** the date returned by the promise. **It is the promise**. You can only get the *data of a promise* when the promise resolves. In this case, the data of the promise is actually `x`
2. Using the `throw` keyword will always cause an exception, which if not handled, will cause an error. In this case, the function will always throw an exception, so I'm not sure what the goal here is.

To actually get the value of the promise within this function there're two ways. Either you `await` the promise or supply a callback function to be called when the promise resolves...

#### Async/Await method

```
export const getFieldChoice = async (key, listName, fieldName) => {
  const value = cache.get(key) || { status: "new", data: null }
  if (value.status === "resolved") return value.data;

  const data = await spApi.lists.getByTitle(listName).fields.getByInternalNameOrTitle(fieldName).select('Choices').get();

  value.data = data;
  value.status = "resolved"
  cache.set(key, value)

  return value;
}
```

and then it's used like this

```
import { getFieldChoice } from "path/to/file";

async function caller () {
  try {
    const key = "key";
    const listName = "list name";
    const fieldName = "field name";

    const data = await getFieldChoice(key, listName, fieldName);
    // Rest of function logic
  } catch (err) {
    // Handle any error
  }
}
```

#### Callback method

```
export const getFieldChoice = (key, listName, fieldName, callback) => {
  const value = cache.get(key) || { status: "new", data: null }
  if (value.status === "resolved") return value.data;


 spApi.lists.getByTitle(listName).fields.getByInternalNameOrTitle(fieldName).select('Choices').get().then(data => {
    value.data = data;
    value.status = "resolved"
    cache.set(key, value)

    callback(null, value);
  }).catch(err => {
    callback(err);
  });
}
```

and then it's used like this

```
import { getFieldChoice } from "path/to/file";

function caller () {
  const key = "key";
  const listName = "list name";
  const fieldName = "field name";

  getFieldChoice(key, listName, fieldName, (err, value) => {
    if (err) {
      // Handle any error
    }

    // Rest of function logic
  });

}
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer. I know how promises works and how to retrieve data from promises with then() or async/await. The thing is here, code above throw the promise, not returning the promise. I asked that is it ok the throw the promise. You said that it is wrong and throw keyword will always cause an exception, and it answers my question. thank you :)